# unable to see Y axis label value on the top of column chart when it reached maximum value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working in .net 4.5 and implementing charting in my asp.net page. everything works fine. i am facing some tricky situation.

Here are my sample values:

X-Axis :  DEC, NOV,OCT,SEP, AUG,JUL

Y-axis value : 0,93,99,0,0,0

I am able to plot the column chart perfectly. i am unable to see the Nov month y axis value on the top of the bar. because it almost the reached the y -axis maximum. i wanted to display 99 on the top of the NOV month column. please help me in this.